# python 2.7 - converting float to bytes and looping through the bytes

Tags: python, serial-port, byte

I'm trying to send a float as a series of 4 bytes over serial.
I have code that looks like this which works:

```
ser.write(b'\xcd') #sending the byte representation of 0.1
ser.write(b'\xcc')
ser.write(b'\xcc') 
ser.write(b'\x3d')
```

but I want to be able to send an arbitary float.

I also want to be able to go through each byte individually so this won't do for example:

```
bytes = struct.pack('f',float(0.1))
ser.write(bytes)
```

because I want to check each byte.

I'm using python 2.7
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to pack the float as binary data. Then loop through each byte of the bytearray and write them to your output.

```
import struct

value = 13.37  # arbitrary float 
bin = struct.pack('f', value)

for b in bin:
    ser.write(b)
```

Comment: Thank you but I hadn't explained the entire problem.

Comment: `struct.pack` returns a bytes object. Perhaps you could loop through each byte and write them. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Great! Here is the [documentation on bytearrays](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) for future referenve. Glad I could help!